# Laravel Websockets - How to get already opened websocket?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am using Laravel Websockets (by BeyondCode) - https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction

Socket connection is working fine, and sending messages via the connection is ok.

Next thing I need is getting my opened connections, so I can send messages via API. If I could somehow get my websocket by socket id (which I have) that would be great. I tried saving the connection variable when it's opened in some config file or session, but it's a really big variable with lot of dependencies.

If anybody had any experience with Laravel Websockets, please help.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Created a custom websocket handler, same like here in the documentation: https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/advanced-usage/custom-websocket-handlers